# Angular ngFor with observable add select value

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, observable, ngfor

I have a ngFo loop like

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let checklist of filterChecklist | async" [value]="checklist.checklistName" (click)="filterList(checklist.checklistName)">
              <span>{{ checklist.checklistName }}</span>
            </mat-option>
```

I want to add an item on Top like 'ALL' or 'Select'

My code in .ts is

```
filterChecklist: any;
    this.filterChecklist = this.dataSharingService.filters();
```

Above retusn observale

How can I do that, 
Plz advise.

Thanks

Comment: use the `placeholder="please select one"` attribute on `mat-select` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't undertand what you need but

just add  `<mat-option>ALL</mat-option>`before your ngFO like this ?

```
<mat-option>ALL</mat-option>
<mat-option *ngFor="let checklist of filterChecklist | async" [value]="checklist.checklistName" (click)="filterList(checklist.checklistName)">
              <span>{{ checklist.checklistName }}</span>
</mat-option>
```